# How to use redirect helper in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to redirect after the login.

After login it has to call the home controller's method.

For example if the url is `test.com`, I have two controllers: `logincontroller` and `home`. So the first url is:

```
test.com/logincontroller/login
```

After that, i want to redirect to

```
test.com/home/getfirstpage
```

So I used redirect function like this

```
redirect("/home/loadfirstpage", 'refresh');
```

But the problem is that the url get screwed up.

After redirect function it goes to this url:

```
test.com/logincontroller/test.com/home/getfirstpage
```

I want to fix to

```
test.com/home/getfirstpage.
```

How can i do this?

---

**Edit**: I'm assuming this is cuz of the .htaccess to delete index.php

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the forward slash you put in the redirect
`redirect("/home/loadfirstpage", 'refresh');` instead do this `redirect("home/loadfirstpage", 'refresh');`

Answer (score 2):

Check your config file and set the `$config[base_url]` correctly.

Load:

```
$this->load->helper('uri');
```

Then in controller:

```
redirect('controller/method', 'refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
redirect("home/loadfirstpage", 'refresh');
```

And set your `.htaccess` file to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And make sure that you have set `$config['index_page']` in `config.php`:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Try all setting proposed by @Mohammad Javad Naderi, but call `redirect('home/loadfirstpage', 'location')`

Comment: Have you set `$config['url_suffix']` in config.php file? Try setting it to `$config['url_suffix'] = '';`